# Android snapchat/MSQRD like face stickers

Tags: android, snapchat

I want to develop live face filters as MSQRD/Snapchat live filters but I didn't able to find out any library or source code for it, can someone please help me to find some path on this topic?

Comment: have you found any solution for this?